# Does minion position matter besides passives?

Tags: hearthstone, hearthstone-mercenaries

I started playing the Mercenaries mode in Hearthstone and I might have missed it during the tutorial, but does minion position matter besides treasure passives. I have come across a passive where Tyrande Whisperwind does more damage to "directly opposite" characters (iirc, I can't find info on different treasures online).

I know that red crits green, green crits blue and blue crits red, but does it matter if they aren't directly opposing the weaker roles on the board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Mercenaries have abilities that rely on their position on the board.

For instance, Cornelius Roame heals nearby mercenaries and Trigore the Lasher damages enemy minions who attack mercenaries at its sides. Therefore, placing them in the middle of the board is a good idea (unless for some reason you only want the effect to hit one of your other mercs but not both).

So, the reply to the title is yes, but it has nothing to do with dealing extra damage to opposite minions. The nearest thing to that is Eudora, whose summoned cannons only damage enemies in front of them (on their own, I'm not counting when they fire because Eudora fires them at target enemy) - and we all know that some damage is more damage than no damage, but it's probably not what you asked for.

On the opposite, there's some rampike dwarves (whose name I can't check because Mercenaries is currently bugged) that attacks whoever is in their front. Still not a question of extra damage, but position matters and not putting a caster in front of them is a wise choice.

Otherwies no, position does not directly influence damage, only color does.